# Spring Boot Apllication crashes while accessing.entries() on redisTemplate.opsForHash(). Throws Jedis connection Error

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am working on a project that uses redis as cache. Now the issue is when the spring boot application starts, the redisTemplate loads. Then it crashes on the line given below.

```
    Map<Object, Object> configCacheKeyValue = redisTemplate.opsForHash()
                .entries("XYZ_configList_" + id);
```

I have added multiple logs as well but I'm unable to point out the issue. What I have tried so far:

1. increase pool size [spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-active=50 ] in application.properties. This worked on local but doesn't do anything on server.
2. redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true); where redis template is being initialized.

So, far only these two solutions are which I found on numerous StackOverflow posts. Can someone point of where might I've messed up?

Also, the build works fine on localhost. I've tested the same using server's redis credentials and it also works on localhost. But it doesn't work on the linux server.
Also, I've verified the dependencies and config file also, but they seem to be alright.

Error log:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'validationController': Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot
> get Jedis connection; nested exception is
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
> a resource from the pool
>
> Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
> Could not get a resource from the pool    at
> redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:59)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:234)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:271)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]    ... 44 common
> frames omitted Caused by:
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed
> connecting to host localhost  :6379   at
> redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:204)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:100)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1866)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:117)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
> ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]    at
> org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
> ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]    at
> org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349)
> ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]    at
> redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   ... 47 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost      at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
> ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
> ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
> redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:181)
> ~[jedis-3.1.0.jar!/:na]   ... 54 common frames omitted

Comment: `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost`